# Why do the derivatives of a function lead towards the extremum of the function?

Tags: optimization, gradient-descent, derivative

Is there some theorem in mathematics that formalizes the idea that "for some function, at a given point, moving in the negative direction of the gradient leads you to some (local) extremum point"?  For example, in the gradient descent algorithm, what exactly justifies the general directions we follow when searching for the optimum point?

Recently, I read about [Fermat's Theorem on Stationary Points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_(stationary_points)), which says that if the point $(a,b)$ is a local extremum for some function $f$ then the derivative of $f$ at the point $(a,b)$ is 0.  Is there some extension of this theorem that states (the obvious idea) that moving in the negative direction of the gradient leads you to this (local) extremum point?  Or is this idea so basic and intuitive that no proof is required?

Comment: The gradient is provably in the direction of steepest ascent, and thus its negative is in the direction of steep descent. The existence of local optima is not guaranteed in general. Fermat's theorem of stationary points is useful insofar as the derivative being zero is a necessary (but not sufficient) condition of local extrema of differentiable functions.

Comment: The gradient descent algorithm will step down the loss surface, which often leads to a local minima in practice. But again, the existence of such local minima is not a certainty.

Comment: What did a search of phrases like *gradient descent convergence* or *steepest descent convergence* yield? (you have surely encountered the term steepest descent or a close synonym) ...  I got a proof (with conditions required for it to eventually yield an optimum) *as a first hit* on a simple search for those phrases. This would seem to fail the usual search/research requirement for questions.

Comment: @ Glen_b: is this what you are talking about? https://www.osti.gov/servlets/purl/983240/#:~:text=The%20steepest%20descent%20method%20is%20one%20of%20the%20oldest%20known,sophisticated%20and%20well%20known%20algorithms.

Comment: I didn't hit that one, no.  https://mdav.ece.gatech.edu/ece-6270-spring2021/notes/06-grad-desc-analysis.pdf (first hit for me with *gradient descent convergence*)  https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/sloan-school-of-management/15-084j-nonlinear-programming-spring-2004/lecture-notes/lec5_steep_desce.pdf (first hit for *steepest descent convergence proof*) or  https://www.math.ucla.edu/~jteran/270c.1.11s/notes_wk4.pdf or  (first hit for *steepest descent convergence*)  ... etc. These were in duckduckgo but generally google does perfectly well. It seems like they each outline proofs with conditions.

Comment: In short there are a number of formalizations (at various levels of formal), depending on the generality you want. Indeed, seeing one of your other posts, it looks like you must already have found some.

Comment: Re "for some function, at a given point, moving in the negative direction of the gradient leads you to some (local) extremum point:" This is not generally true.  As a counterexample, follow the gradient of the function $(x,y)\to xy.$  If it converges, it will take you to $(0,0)$ which obviously is not an extremum.  Gradients take you either to *critical points* or they follow an infinite curve (which might or might not move arbitrarily far from the starting point: the curve can remain in a bounded region).  This is the subject of so-called "advanced Calculus."

Answer (score 5):

##### Steepest ascent (descent) occurs in the direction (opposite direction) of the gradient

All theorems in mathematics are proved through detailed steps, even if the result is "obvious".  So as to your general question, no, it is not too obvious to require proof.  (When a result is an obvioius conseqeuence of some other result, such that it does not require proof, we call it a "corollary" rather than a "theorem".)  This particular result is proved through a combination of the multivariate chain rule and the geometric form for the dot product.

To get this result, consider a differentiable multivariate function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with gradient vector $\nabla f$, and suppose we choose a point $\mathbf{x} = (x_1,...,x_n)$ and a direction vector $\mathbf{u} = (u_1,...,u_n)$.  Applying the [multivariate chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule#Multivariable_case) to the path function $\mathbf{x}(t) = \mathbf{x} + \mathbf{u} t$ we find that the **directional derivative** in the direction $\mathbf{u}$ from the point $\mathbf{x}$ is given by:

$$f_\mathbf{u}(\mathbf{x}) \equiv \frac{\partial f}{\partial \mathbf{u}}(\mathbf{x})
= \mathbf{u} \cdot \nabla f (\mathbf{x}).$$

Now, suppose we let $0 \leqslant \theta \leqslant \pi$ be the angle (in radians) between the direction vector $\mathbf{u}$ and the gradient vector $\nabla f(\mathbf{x})$.  Since $\mathbf{u}$ is a direction vector it has unit length, so we can apply the [geometric meaning of the dot product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Geometric_definition) to write the directional derivative as:

$$\begin{align}
f_\mathbf{u}(\mathbf{x}) 
&= \mathbf{u} \cdot \nabla f (\mathbf{x}) \\[6pt]
&= ||\mathbf{u}|| \ ||\nabla f (\mathbf{x})|| \cos \theta \\[6pt]
&= ||\nabla f (\mathbf{x})|| \cos \theta. \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

The only thing in this equation that depends on the direction $\mathbf{u}$ is the angle $\theta$, so the directional derivative is affected by the direction only through this angle.  The steepest ascent occurs when $f_\mathbf{u}(\mathbf{x})$ is maximised for $\theta$, which occurs when the cosine of this angle is the *most positive*.  The steepest descent occurs when $f_\mathbf{u}(\mathbf{x})$ is minimised for $\theta$, which occurs when the cosine of this angle is the *most negative*.  Consequently, the angles giving steepest ascent/descent are as follows:$^\dagger$

$$\begin{matrix}
\text{Steepest ascent} & & \cos \theta = 1 \ \ \ & & \theta = 0 & & \text{(direction of gradient vector)} \\[6pt]
\text{Steepest descent} & & \cos \theta = -1 & & \theta = \pi & & \text{(opposite direction of gradient vector)} \\[6pt]
\end{matrix}$$

Another consequence of this result is that the gradient vector at a point $\mathbf{x}$ is always orthogonal to any tangent to the level curve of the function at that point.

---

$^\dagger$ This sets aside the special case where $\mathbf{x}$ is a critical point (i.e., when $\nabla f (\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{0}$).  In this case the directional derivative is zero in all directions, so the steepest ascent/descent occurs (trivially) in any direction.

Comment: The connection between this and the specific question being asked is a little obscure: see the title.

Comment: It may be worth observing that this notion of "steepest" is somewhat arbitrary, since it depends on a default Euclidean metric (in which $\mathbf{u}$ is a unit vector) and is not invariant to a change of variables. More generally, moving in the direction $\mathsf{A} \cdot \boldsymbol{\nabla}f$ increases $f$ for any positive definite matrix $\mathsf{A}$. Indeed, an appropriate choice of $\mathsf{A}$ (related to second derivatives of $f$) makes the approach to a local extremum much more efficient as a numerical method.